# How can I make the whole circle clickable ( now it is just the center which is clickable )

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Could someone help me to make this circle works as buttons ( whole circle clickable not even the centre )

Thank you in advance :
( as said >> right now it is only the center which is clickable not the whole circle, really thanks for everyone :)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>


  <style>
    div#timeline {
      background-color: #6ab0de;
      margin-top: 150px;
      height: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    div#timeline .inside {
      position: absolute;
      height: 4px;
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 0%;
      top: 3px;
      left: 0;
    }
    div#timeline .dot {
      z-index: 99;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      top: -15px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    div#timeline .dot:nth-child(1) {
      left: 10%;
    }
    div#timeline .dot:nth-child(2) {
      left: 20%;
      background-color: #e74c3c;
    }
    div#timeline .dot:nth-child(3) {
      left: 30%;
      background-color: #7b3;
    }
    div#timeline .dot:nth-child(4) {
      left: 40%;
      background-color: #20638f;
    }
    div#timeline .dot:nth-child(5) {
      left: 50%;
      background-color: #7cdbd5;
    }
    div#timeline .dot:nth-child(6) {
      left: 60%;
      background-color: #f39c12;
    }
    div#timeline .dot:nth-child(7) {
      left: 70%;
      background-color: #2c3e50;
    }
    div#timeline .dot:nth-child(8) {
      left: 80%;
      background-color: #e74c3c;
    }
    div#timeline .dot:nth-child(9) {
      left: 90%;
      background-color: #7b3;
    }
    div#timeline .dot:hover {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    div#timeline .dot date {
      font-family: roboto;
      font-size: 1.1rem;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      top: -60px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    div#timeline .dot span {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 10px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: #fff;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
  </style>

</head>





<body>


  <div id="timeline">




    <div class="dot" id="1" style="background-color: #2c3e50;">
      <span></span>
      <date>P2</date>
    </div>

    <div class="dot" id="2">
      <span></span>
      <date>P2</date>
    </div>

    <div class="dot" id="3">
      <span></span>
      <date>P3</date>
    </div>

    <div class="dot" id="4">
      <span></span>
      <date>P4</date>
    </div>

    <div class="dot" id="5">
      <span></span>
      <date>P5</date>
    </div>

    <div class="dot" id="6">
      <span></span>
      <date>P5</date>
    </div>

    <div class="dot" id="7">
      <span></span>
      <date>P5</date>
    </div>

    <div class="dot" id="8">
      <span></span>
      <date>P5</date>
    </div>

    <div class="dot" id="9">
      <span></span>
      <date>P5</date>
    </div>



    <div class="inside"></div>
  </div>







  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    $('.dot:nth-child(1)').click(function() {
      $('.inside', $(this).parent()).animate({
        'width': '10%'
      }, 500);
    });
    $('.dot:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
      $('.inside', $(this).parent()).animate({
        'width': '20%'
      }, 500);
    });
    $('.dot:nth-child(3)').click(function() {
      $('.inside', $(this).parent()).animate({
        'width': '30%'
      }, 500);
    });
    $('.dot:nth-child(4)').click(function() {
      $('.inside', $(this).parent()).animate({
        'width': '40%'
      }, 500);
    });
    $('.dot:nth-child(5)').click(function() {
      $('.inside', $(this).parent()).animate({
        'width': '50%'
      }, 500);
    });
    $('.dot:nth-child(6)').click(function() {
      $('.inside', $(this).parent()).animate({
        'width': '60%'
      }, 500);
    });
    $('.dot:nth-child(7)').click(function() {
      $('.inside', $(this).parent()).animate({
        'width': '70%'
      }, 500);
    });
    $('.dot:nth-child(8)').click(function() {
      $('.inside', $(this).parent()).animate({
        'width': '80%'
      }, 500);
    });
    $('.dot:nth-child(9)').click(function() {
      $('.inside', $(this).parent()).animate({
        'width': '90%'
      }, 500);
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you mean "circle"? I can click even the outer pixels of the border, not only the center. What browser are you using?

Comment: Works ok for me.
Have you added `JQuery` to your page ?

Comment: Hi, 
Actually only the center of each cercle is clickable but the border of the cercle is not!

Comment: Hi, 
Actually only the center of each cercle is clickable but the border of the cercle is not!
I am using the latest version of firefox 
does someone have an idea to make the whole cercle clickable and not only the center
Of course, the blank line is working fine but i am talking about click not the blank line inside the heavy line... 
really thanks :)

Comment: It works fine in my FF.

Comment: Working fine in Chrome

Comment: Can you please stop insisting on "cercle" and understand that it is "circle"?

Comment: Have you considered putting an anchor tag around the circle and simply moving the onClick event to that? Seems like the most simple way to achieve what you want...

Comment: Thank you Leo and all of the other contributers but how can i do that ?
what do you mean by anchor tag ? do you have an example please?

Comment: It is ok,
Leo was right, by arounding my div with link href tag it works fine
thanks to everyone :)